# nsubstitute property getter override does not work

Tags: c#, nsubstitute

I am a newbie at testing with nsubstitute. So maybe this is a trivial question to you. But I can't find one. I please you to help me with the following problem.

I have a problem by testing an abstract class:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public string Name
    {
        get { return GetName(); }
        set { SetName(value); }
    }

    protected abstract string GetName();

    protected abstract void SetName(string value);

}
```

I want to test, if the getter and the setter is called properly in the abstract class. To fetch the protected abstract methods I derived the class:

```
public class MockClass:BaseClass
{
    protected override string GetName()
    {
        return MockGetName();
    }

    protected override void SetName(string value)
    {
        MockSetName(value);
    }

    public virtual string MockGetName()
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }

    public virtual void MockSetName(string value)
    {
    }
}
```

And now I wanted to test, if the MockGetName()-Method is called, when getting the value of the Name-Property by:

```
public void TestNameGetter()
{
    // arrange
    MockClass mock = Substitute.For<MockClass>();
    mock.MockGetName().Returns(" Irgendein Name ");

    // act
    string name = mock.Name;

    // assert
    Assert.AreEqual(" Irgendein Name ", name, "Wrong name");
    mock.DidNotReceive().MockSetName(Arg.Any<string>());
    mock.Received().MockGetName();
}
```

But the method MockGetName is never called and the variable name has the wrong value.

I hope that anyone can help me to test the functionality. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that NSubstitute is intercepting the `MockClass.GetName` call and returning the default for that (empty string). So when `mock.Name` runs in the test, it calls `GetName` and we get the empty string back, regardless of what `MockGetName` would return.

I'm unsure of exactly what you're trying to achieve, but the first options that came to mind if you want to use NSubstitute for this sort of thing are to use the property directly, or to change `GetName` to public. Alternatively, avoid NSubstitute and put the logic you need for your test directly into your `MockClass`.

**Mockable property**

```
    public abstract class BaseClass
    {
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestNameGetter()
    {
        var mock = Substitute.For<BaseClass>();
        mock.Name.Returns("ABC");

        string name = mock.Name;

        Assert.AreEqual("ABC", name, "Wrong name");
    }
```

**Public accessor methods**

```
    public abstract class BaseClass
    {
        public string Name
        {
            get { return GetName(); }
            set { SetName(value); }
        }

        public abstract string GetName();
        public abstract void SetName(string value);
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestNameGetter()
    {
        var mock = Substitute.For<BaseClass>();
        mock.GetName().Returns("ABC");

        string name = mock.Name;

        Assert.AreEqual("ABC", name, "Wrong name");
        mock.DidNotReceive().SetName(Arg.Any<string>());
        mock.Received().GetName();
    }
```

**Hand-coded mock**

```
    public class MockClass : BaseClass
    {
        public bool GetNameWasCalled = false;
        public bool SetNameWasCalled = false;
        protected override string GetName() { GetNameWasCalled = true; return "ABC"; }
        protected override void SetName(string value) { SetNameWasCalled = true; }
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestNameGetter()
    {
        // arrange
        var mock = new MockClass();

        // act
        string name = mock.Name;

        // assert
        Assert.AreEqual("ABC", name, "Wrong name");
        Assert.False(mock.SetNameWasCalled);
        Assert.True(mock.GetNameWasCalled);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks David for your response. I tried to test the behaviour, that the setter method is called, when the property is set and the getter method is calle, when the properties values is gotten.
I think the third solution is good. The first does not test what I wanted to be tested. The second does not fit for me, because I want to have the getter and setter methods unvisible to outer classes.

Comment: If you use an auto-property you'll get that for free! :)

Comment: Your right if there is just one class, but there are several classes inheriting from the Baseclass that handle the property in different ways.

Comment: Right, so can you just test what happens for each subclass when get/set is called? Don't need to explicitly assert that they were called, it is guaranteed by C#.